# How to remove a UIGestureRecognizer from a table cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, xcode4.2, uigesturerecognizer

I want to only allow swipe to delete on the first cell of a `UITableView`.
This bit is easy, however I want to display a `UIAlert` when the user tries to swipe any other cell. Again I have this working by using `UIGestureRecognizer` on each cell apart from cell 0.

The problem i'm having is once the top row has been deleted, I want the new top row to be allowed to be deleted.
It's as if I need to remove the `UIGestureRecognizer's` i've assigned to the cell, but I can't figure out how to.

Here is some of my code

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    BetCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"BetCell"];

    Bet *bet = [self.bets objectAtIndex:([self.bets count]-indexPath.row-1)];
    cell.BFNeedLabel.text = bet.BFNeeded;

    if (indexPath.row != 0) {
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeDetected:)];
    swipeRecognizer.direction = (UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft | UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight);
    [cell addGestureRecognizer:swipeRecognizer];
    }

    return cell;

}

-(void)swipeDetected:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Info" message:@"You can only delete starting from the top cell" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}

-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        return YES;
    } else  { 
        return NO;
    }
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // If the very first row
    if ((editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) && (indexPath.row == 0)) {
        Bet *betObj = [self.bets objectAtIndex:([self.bets count]-indexPath.row-1)];
        //Delete from array
        [self.bets removeObjectAtIndex:([self.bets count]-indexPath.row-1)];
        //Delete the row
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

        //Attempt to remove gesture recognizer from cell 0
        UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeDetected:)];
        swipeRecognizer.direction = (UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft | UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight);
        [[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:0]removeGestureRecognizer:swipeRecognizer];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to remove the gestureRecognizer. In your `swipeDetected` find out which cell you are, and only show the alert if `indexPath.row != 0`.

Your gesture recognizer will give you the location which can be translated to the table view coordinate space which turn can be used to get the indexPath for that cell.

In `swipeDetected`

```
CGPoint location = [sender locationInView:self.tableView];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:location];
if ( indexPath.row != 0 {
// do alert
}
```

**Update with sample code:**

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 20;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Test"];
    if ( !cell ) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"test"] autorelease];
        UISwipeGestureRecognizer *gr = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleCellSwipe:)];
        gr.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight + UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
        gr.delegate = self;
        [cell addGestureRecognizer:gr];
        [gr release];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell %d",indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}

- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ( indexPath.row == 0 )
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
    else 
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return indexPath.row == 0;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // do stuff
}

- (void)handleCellSwipe:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    if ( gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized ) {
        CGPoint location = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.tableView];
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:location];
        if ( indexPath.row != 0 ) {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cell Swipe"
                                                            message:@"Cell in row not equal to 0 swiped"
                                                           delegate:nil 
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                                  otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
            [alert show];
            [alert release];
        }
    }
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.tableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:location];
    return indexPath.row != 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i'm nearly there.
This now doesn't show the alert on the new top row, however it doesn't show the delete button because swiping is running the swipeDetected code and not the commitEditingStyle code like it does for the first one before it's deleted.

Comment: Hmmm... good point. Make the cell the delegate of your gesture recognizer, implement `- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch;` and using similar logic as in `swipeDetected`, return NO if `indexPath.row==0`

Comment: Too late to edit comment: Make the controller the delegate, not the cell. Had my mind on a different question I was also working on.

Comment: It still doesn't seem to be working. I have the controller as delegate and have this which doesn't seem to make a difference:
`- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.tableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexpath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:location];
    if (indexpath.row == 0) {
        return NO;
    } else {
        return YES;
    }
}`

Comment: Hmmm... I just put together a quick sample project and test it as you are describing you want it to work. I'll post the code.

Comment: You are a star thank you. Working Now.
I hadn't actually set the delegate of GestureRecognizer's to self.
`gr.delegate = self;`

Comment: Glad it helped you out. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Why go through the trouble of a gesture recognizer when you can just show the alert through the caneditrowatindexpath. Only problem I can see is if you also use an edit button - then you'll get a lot of alerts at once.

```
-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        return YES;
    } else  { 
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Info" message:@"You can only delete starting from the top cell" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}
```

If your set on using the gesture recognizer you'll just have to use reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation: on index 0 after the delete this will reset the first cell. However your cellforrowatindexpath is set up wrong in your original post and will cause weird things to happen for this setup either way.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    BetCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"BetCell"];

    if ( !cell ) //this is needed in case a cell was never created in the first place
        cell = [[[BetCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"BetCell"] autorelease];

    Bet *bet = [self.bets objectAtIndex:([self.bets count]-indexPath.row-1)];
    cell.BFNeedLabel.text = bet.BFNeeded;

    if (indexPath.row != 0) {
        UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeDetected:)];
        swipeRecognizer.direction = (UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft | UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight);
        [cell addGestureRecognizer:swipeRecognizer];
    } else {//this is needed to reset a cell that is being reused (such as when you scroll off the page and return)
        for (UIGestureRecognizer *gesture in cell.gestureRecognizers) {
            [cell removeGestureRecognizer:gesture];
        }
    }

    return cell;

}
```

Comment: I got it working as above and a lot more code.
The reason I didn't want to just use canEditRow is I didnt want the edit button showing on rows apart from row 0, but I didn't want just nothing to happen on the other rows so the user thinks delete isn't an option. Now they get an alert if they try to swipe any row but row 0